# Zimbra 7.2 reverse proxy to arbitrary internal website?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, zimbra

I have ZCS 7.2 opensource installed at webmail.domain.com and mailman on mailman.domain.com/mailman.

I wanted to setup a proxy so that when someone goes to webmail.domain.com/mailman, the proxy would instead pull up the contents of mailman.domain.com/mailman.

With apache and mod_proxy I could do something like
ProxyPass /mailman https://mailman.domain.com/mailman
ProxyPassReverse /mailman https://mailman.domain.com/mailman

With the amount of customization in zimbra, is it possible (and advisable) to do the same with zimbra's web server? So basically a reverse proxy that forwards to an arbitrary internal website.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link:
http://www.maxxer.it/2010/linux/set-apache2-to-proxy-zimbra/

I've successfully proxied Zimbra using Apache2 for long time.

These commands work on Debian/Ubuntu servers.

At first, enable apache2′s modules:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_html
a2enmod proxy_http
```

Make sure the use of mod_proxy is allowed, by changing /etc/apache2/mods_available/proxy.conf

```
Allow from all
```

In this case I want to proxy SSL, so before starting you will need to move Zimbra HTTPS away from port 443 (I moved to 444). Copy your Zimbra certificate files to a directory accessible by apache. I choose /etc/apache2/ssl.

To allow automatic redirect from / to /zimbra, as in your normal Zimbra install, add the following line to your main  stanza:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /zimbra/
Then, edit you apache2 config file and add:

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/host.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/host.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia full
<Location "/service">
  ProxyPass https://your_zimbra_ip:444/service
  ProxyPassReverse https://your_zimbra_ip:444/service
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLExtended      On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /service /service
</Location>

<Location "/zimbra">
  ProxyPass https://your_zimbra_ip:444/zimbra
  ProxyPassReverse https://your_zimbra_ip:444/zimbra
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLExtended      On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /zimbra /zimbra
</Location>

<Location "/home">
  ProxyPass https://your_zimbra_ip:444/home
  ProxyPassReverse https://your_zimbra_ip:444/home
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLExtended      On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /home /home
</Location>

# CalDAV
<Location "/principals">
  ProxyPass https://your_zimbra_ip:444/principals
  ProxyPassReverse https://your_zimbra_ip:444/principals
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLExtended      On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /principals /principals
</Location>
# DAV
<Location "/dav">
  ProxyPass https://your_zimbra_ip:444/dav
  ProxyPassReverse https://your_zimbra_ip:444/dav
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLExtended      On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /dav /dav
</Location>
#Printing and HTML interface
<Location "/h">
  ProxyPass https://your_zimbra_ip:444/h
  ProxyPassReverse https://your_zimbra_ip:444/h
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLExtended      On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /h /h
</Location>

# img for mobile interface
<Location "/img">
  ProxyPass https://your_zimbra_ip:444/img
  ProxyPassReverse https://your_zimbra_ip:444/img
  ProxyPassReverse /
  ProxyHTMLExtended      On
  ProxyHTMLURLMap /img /img
</Location>
```

Restart your apache2, and you should be done!
P.S. in case you wish to proxy https:

```
a2enmod ssl
```

Add the following to your /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia full
```